# iScroll not working if touch events are enabled

Tags: javascript, scroll, iscroll

I am using iscroll.js (v4.1.9) but if i enabled the touch events (Enable touch events) under chrome://flags/ in chrome browser. User is not able to scroll the panel in which iScroll is used.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with Chrome and horizontal scrolling touch events. I found the solution to my problem [here](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/1100).

TLDR: Had to disable pointer events in iscroll and enable touch events

```
this.iscroll = new IScroll(this.iscrollEl, {
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: false,
    mouseWheel: false,
    disablePointer: true,
    disableTouch: false,
    disableMouse: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with version 5.2.0. I had to modify the JS...look for 
hasPointer: !(!t.PointerEvent && !t.MSPointerEvent) and change it to 
hasPointer: 0

which of course only works on mobile devices, which was my issue